# Who were all the dancers?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

At the ball of the Mephisto Waltz, we see quite a number of masked dancers streaming down the staircase behind Sabrina. I counted at least 12, but probably more.

However, the only people who could have been at the ball are Zelda, Hilda, Ambrose, Prudence, Lilith, Nick, Harvey, Theo, Roz, for a total of nine people, which is the number we see in a better lit later scene. The other coven members were still being treated for poisoning.

What's going on here? Are there actually fewer people than it seems? A glamour to seemingly multiply the numbers? Were they able to revive a few coven members?